# Group people which have different locations

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting, grouping

I need help. My function to group people does not really work. The problem is quite simple:

I have a dataframe with following columns:

- latitude
- longitude
- floor

These columns are random locations of people.
The dataframe has a length of multiple of 9 (in this example the length is 36. I reality it is much longer).

**I want to group people by the following idea:**

First I create a new column with the name "group".
People who live close together (according to coordinates) are assigned to a specific group number (1, 2 3,...). Each group contains 3 people.

**Now the tricky part:** People with identical coordinates **can not be in the same group**!

This is how I did it:

Here is the data:

```
array_data=([[ 50.56419  ,   8.67667  ,   2.       , 160.       ],
   [ 50.5643136,   8.6772816,   3.       ,  89.       ],
   [ 50.5646274,   8.6763909,   0.       , 259.       ],
   [ 50.5661047,   8.6765931,   1.       , 100.       ],
   [ 50.5663442,   8.6575205,   1.       , 117.       ],
   [ 50.56686  ,   8.67598  ,   1.       ,  95.       ],
   [ 50.56747  ,   8.67604  ,   2.       , 199.       ],
   [ 50.56762  ,   8.6702799,   0.       , 148.       ],
   [ 50.5693473,   8.6640855,  -1.       ,  50.       ],
   [ 50.5693473,   8.6640855,   0.       , 111.       ],
   [ 50.5705819,   8.6597279,   2.       , 183.       ],
   [ 50.57067  ,   8.65694  ,   2.       , 257.       ],
   [ 50.57075  ,   8.65748  ,   1.       , 211.       ],
   [ 50.57075  ,   8.65748  ,   1.       , 292.       ],
   [ 50.5722461,   8.6598248,   2.       , 142.       ],
   [ 50.57254  ,   8.65895  ,   1.       , 116.       ],
   [ 50.57259  ,   8.6592   ,   2.       , 228.       ],
   [ 50.5731636,   8.667609 ,   1.       , 181.       ],
   [ 50.5737814,   8.6720067,   0.       , 173.       ],
   [ 50.5740356,   8.6718179,   1.       ,   5.       ],
   [ 50.5746321,   8.6831284,   3.       , 202.       ],
   [ 50.5747453,   8.6765588,   4.       , 119.       ],
   [ 50.5748992,   8.6611471,   2.       , 260.       ],
   [ 50.5748992,   8.6611471,   3.       , 102.       ],
   [ 50.575    ,   8.65985  ,   2.       , 267.       ],
   [ 50.5751   ,   8.66027  ,   2.       ,   7.       ],
   [ 50.5751   ,   8.66027  ,   2.       ,  56.       ],
   [ 50.57536  ,   8.67741  ,   1.       , 194.       ],
   [ 50.57536  ,   8.67741  ,   1.       , 282.       ],
   [ 50.5755255,   8.6884584,   0.       , 276.       ],
   [ 50.5755273,   8.674282 ,   3.       , 167.       ],
   [ 50.57553  ,   8.6826   ,   2.       , 273.       ],
   [ 50.5755973,   8.6847492,   0.       , 168.       ],
   [ 50.5756757,   8.6846139,   4.       , 255.       ],
   [ 50.57572  ,   8.65965  ,   0.       ,  66.       ],
   [ 50.57591  ,   8.68175  ,   1.       , 187.       ]])
```

Convert array to dataframe and rename the columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=array_data) # convert back to dataframe

df.rename(columns={0: 'latitude', 1: 'longitude', 2:'floor', 3:'id'}, inplace=True) # rename columns
```

Now we have the dataframe. With the following functions I was trying to group the people:

First we need to find a way, to get the distances to the people:

```
def calculate_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    """
    Calculate the shortest distance between two points given by the latitude and
    longitude.
    """
    earth_radius = 6373  # Approximate / in km.
    lat1 = radians(lat1)
    lon1 = radians(lon1)
    lat2 = radians(lat2)
    lon2 = radians(lon2)

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = sin(dlat / 2) ** 2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2) ** 2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    return earth_radius * c  # in km.
```

And here is the main function. I try to group people if they have NOT the same location:

```
def sort_people(all_persons, max_distance_parameter):

    '''
    People in the same group have different location!
    '''

    assert len(all_persons) % 9 == 0
    all_persons.set_index("id", drop=False, inplace=True)

    all_persons["host"] = np.nan
    all_persons["group"] = np.nan

    scattering_factor= 0.0001  # to seperate same floor numbers
    max_distance = max_distance_parameter
    group_number = 0
    group = []
    for _, candidate in all_persons.iterrows():
        if len(group) == 3:
            for person in group:
                all_persons.at[person["id"], "group"] = group_number
            group_number += 1
            group = []

        if len(group) == 0:
            group.append(candidate)
        else:
            for person in group:
                distance = calculate_distance(
                    candidate["latitude"],
                    candidate["longitude"],
                    person["latitude"],
                    person["longitude"],
                )
                distance = distance 

                if candidate['floor'] == -1:                 # consider the floor when calculating the distance 
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.001
                elif candidate['floor'] == 0:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.002
                elif candidate['floor'] == 1:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.003
                elif candidate['floor'] == 2:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.004
                elif candidate['floor'] == 3:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.005
                elif candidate['floor'] == 4:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.006
                elif candidate['floor'] == 5:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.007
                elif candidate['floor'] == 6:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.008
                elif candidate['floor'] == 7:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.009
                elif candidate['floor'] == 8:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.010
                elif candidate['floor'] == 9:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.011
                elif candidate['floor'] == 10:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.012
                elif candidate['floor'] == 11:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.013
                elif candidate['floor'] == 12:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.014
                elif candidate['floor'] == 13:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.015
                elif candidate['floor'] == 14:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.016
                else:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.017

                if 0 < distance <= max_distance:
                    group.append(candidate)
                    break
```

Long story short: this doesn't really work. At the end, I get a dataframe and I find people in the same locations which are assigned to the same group. How would you do it?

Answer (score 2):

Using your solution, add logic to see if the person with same coordinates is already in the group. When you check if the group has no people, add. But if there is a person in the group, for each person in the group calculate the distance between that person and the candidate. If it is 0, then break(exit and don't add the person to that group). Then go to next group and do the same.

Btw. I'm not familiar with this programming language so I might've written bad syntax, so please use the above pseudocode to be a guide. Cheers!

```
if len(group) == 0:
            group.append(candidate)
        else:
            for person in group:

                distance = calculate_distance(
                    candidate["latitude"],
                    candidate["longitude"],
                    person["latitude"],
                    person["longitude"],
                )
                distance = distance 

                **if distance == 0 : break;** 

                if candidate['floor'] == -1:                 # consider the floor when calculating the distance 
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.001
                elif candidate['floor'] == 0:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.002
                elif candidate['floor'] == 1:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.003
                elif candidate['floor'] == 2:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.004
                elif candidate['floor'] == 3:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.005
                elif candidate['floor'] == 4:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.006
                elif candidate['floor'] == 5:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.007
                elif candidate['floor'] == 6:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.008
                elif candidate['floor'] == 7:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.009
                elif candidate['floor'] == 8:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.010
                elif candidate['floor'] == 9:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.011
                elif candidate['floor'] == 10:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.012
                elif candidate['floor'] == 11:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.013
                elif candidate['floor'] == 12:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.014
                elif candidate['floor'] == 13:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.015
                elif candidate['floor'] == 14:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.016
                else:
                  distance = distance + scattering_factor + 0.017

                if 0 < distance <= max_distance:
                    group.append(candidate)
                    break
```

Comment: The syntax is not Python. Maybe I can fix that. Can you please tell me, how to make sure that every group contains 3 people. Not more and not less.

Comment: that'd be pretty easy. in the part where you start adding people to a group, count to 3 and after it becomes 3, continue to the next loop iteration(which represents the next group) btw. I'm helping just becausec you're spiderman